# Get prioritized (by popularity) list from different lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, tuples

This functionality is somewhat similar to Stack Overflow badges.

I have a list of friends, and for these friends I can get all their badges with the method:

> GetBadgesFromUser(string user)

I now need to get a list of all the badges from my friends, ordered by their popularity.

I have the following code so far:

```
public List<string> GetRankedBadgeList()
{
    List<Tuple<string, int>> rankedBadgeList = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

    List<string> friendList = new List<String>();
    List<string> badgesList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var friend in friendList)
    {
        var badges = GetBadgesFromUser(friend);
        if (badges == null || !badges.Any()) continue;
        rankedBadgeList = AddBadges(badges, rankedBadgeList);
    }

    return rankedBadgeList.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList();
}

private List<Tuple<string, int>> AddBadges(List<string> badges, List<Tuple<string, int>> rankedBadgeList)
{
    List<Tuple<string, int>> badgesRevisited = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
    foreach (string badge in badges) 
    {
        foreach (var rankedBadge in rankedBadgeList)
        {
            if (rankedBadge.Item1 == badge)
                badgesRevisited.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(rankedBadge.Item1, rankedBadge.Item2 + 1));
            else
                badgesRevisited.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(badge, 0));
        }
    }
    return badgesRevisited;
}
```

I use the object `List<Tuple<string, int>>` to get all the badges without duplicates, and use the `int` value to store the number of matches.
I will traverse the list and order the items based on their popularity (`int` value).

The thing is that I am not completely sure this is the best approach, maybe the tuple is not the best for the job.

Comment: What makes you think that the tuple is inappropriate? I like tuples as long as they don't leave my class, so either method or class scope at a maximum. But as always, a good replacement for tuples are real classes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because I thought I could use the method sort from tuples to order the list once I have the popularity, but I think that will not be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a linq "one liner" quite easily.

```
var orderedBadges = friendList
    .SelectMany(f=>GetBadgesFromUser(f))
    .GroupBy(b=>b)
    .Select(g=>new {Badge=g.Key, Count=g.Count()})
    .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count)
    .Select(x=>x.Badge);
```

What this does is takes your friend list and converts that to a list of all badges using `SelectMany`. This will have duplicates as appropriate.

It then groups them up and it then creates an anonymous object with the badge name, uses the count on this object to order them and then just extracts the badge name for your final `IEnumerable<string>`.

I should note that you probably don't need the anonymous object in the middle but I included it because it aids clarity a bit.

Comment: Could you please, explain to me, what happens with the duplicates?

Comment: I ask, because the method to Add, was not including duplicates

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx is the group by method I used. When you use group by it groups them up into an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. There will be one grouping per key. The key is our badge so we have one group per badge. The group is then itself an Enumerable which contains one entry for each of the duplicates which we then count. So in the line after the group by (and from then on ) our `IEnumerable` only has one entry per badge.

Comment: you are completely right, my bad. I will test it and give you feedback

Comment: @DanielV: Not a problem. I'm glad you asked to give me a chance to explain. This site is all about the learning. :) I should note that I haven't compiled that code so it might have typos or such like in there but I think it is good.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `List<Tuple<string, int>>` and the complete implementation of `AddBadges` you can use LINQ, which returns what you need:

```
badges
   .GroupBy(p => p)
   .Select(group => new { Badge = group.Key, Count = group.Count()})
   .OrderByDescending(group => group.Count);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable` of an anomyous type with a `Badge` property (the original string in the `badges` list, and a `Count` property, ordered by the `Count` property (descending).

So you'd just need something like

```
foreach (var friend in friendList)
{
    var badges = GetBadgesFromUser(friend);
    if (badges == null || !badges.Any()) continue;
    rankedBadgeList.AddRange(<the LINQ statement above>);
}

return rankedBadgeList.Select(x => x.Badge).ToList();
```

Comment: Your LINQ statement looks good but on reading further your use of it is bizarre. the badges that you are applying this linq to are just a single users badges so presumably will already be unique? Even if not if you consider you have three friends all with the same single badge then your loop will add that to your rankedBadgeList three times. You are basically sorting sub lists and then concatenating them rather than sorting your final list once all the data is in it.